# Independence of events - drawing balls with replacement and writing down their numbers

Tags: probability

I have got a following problem:
$$ $$
We have a box with $n$ numbered balls (from $1$ to $n$). We draw them with replacement. We write down on a sheet of paper a number of a ball we draw, if it didn't appear yet in previous drawings. (for example. We draw $6$, we write it down and put the ball again in the box. We draw $2$, we write it down. We draw $6$ again and we don't write it down again, we just return it to the box. ETC) We continue until we obtain all possible numbers. 
$$ $$
Let $A_j$ be the event that $j$-th and $(j+1)$-th numbers on our sheet of paper appeared there after two FOLLOWING drawings. $j \in \{1,2, ... ,n-1\} $
Check the independence of events $A_j$.

$$ $$
So I want to find if the random family $A_{i_1}, ... , A_{i_k}$ is independent ($i_1 , ... i_k$ are not necessarily consecutive numbers).
$$ $$
I found the probability of the single event. It is: $P(A_j) = \frac{n-j}{n}$, because we have to draw a ball we haven't drawn yet. So I know the probability $P(A_{i_1}) ... P(A_{i_k})$.

$$ $$
But I do not know, how to find probability of $P(A_{i_1} \cap ... \cap A_{i_k})$. Can somebody show me how to do it? My intuition is that it is going to be independent, but I would like a formal argument, which I don't know how to find. I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: $P(A_j \cap A_{j+1}) = \frac{n-j}{n} \times \frac{n-j-1}{n}$ since after drawing the $j^{\text{th}}$ distinct ball you immediately have to draw a ball you have not drawn yet and then immediately have to draw another ball you have not drawn yet

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

It is sufficient to prove that $P\left[B_{1}\cap\cdots\cap B_{n-1}\right]=P\left(B_{1}\right)\times\cdots\times P\left(B_{n-1}\right)$
whenever $B_{i}\in\left\{ A_{i},A_{i}^{c}\right\} $ for $i=1,\dots,n-1$.

You can probably do that with induction to $n$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can without loss of generality check the independence of $A_j$ and $A_{j+1}$, since, if these are independent then $A_j$, $A_k$ are independent for all $j \not= k$.

So, since $P(A_j \cap A_{j+1})$ is the same as $(j+1)$th draw yielding a consecutive number and $(j+2)$th draw again yielding a consecutive number, 
$$
P(A_j \cap A_{j+1}) = \left(\frac{n-j}{n}\right)\left(\frac{n-(j+1)}{n}\right)=P(A_j)P(A_{j+1})
$$ 
so they are independent.

Comment: yeah, but what about more than two events? Like independence of $i$ events?

Comment: Well, if any two events are independent, then so are any 3 and so on. Probability of drawing all numbers consecuteivly, for example, will be
$$
\prod^{n-1}_{i=1}P(A_i)
$$